# Multiple Joins with Sums

Tags: postgresql, rails

Here is my basic schema

**wbs_item**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | name      | parent_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | Materials |           |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | Drywall   | 1         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 3  | Plumbing  | 1         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 4  | Labour    |           |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 5  | Drywall   | 2         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 6  | Plumbing  | 2         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

The idea here is their is a hierarchy to breakdown the costs on the budget.

**budgets**

- id

**budget_items**

```
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| id | budget_id | wbs_item_id | name        | total |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 1  | 1         | 2           | Sheet Goods | 1000  |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 2  | 1         | 2           | Mud / Tape  | 100   |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 3  | 1         | 5           | Main Floor  | 500   |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 4  | 1         | 5           | Basement    | 500   |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 5  | 1         | 3           | Rough-in    | 500   |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 6  | 1         | 6           | Rough-in    | 1000  |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

Here is what I am try to output

```
+---------------------------+
| Materials                 |
+--------------------+------+
|   Drywall          | 1100 |
+--------------------+------+
|   Plumbing         | 500  |
+--------------------+------+
| Total (Materials): | 1600 |
+--------------------+------+
| Labour                    |
+--------------------+------+
|   Drywall          | 1000 |
+--------------------+------+
|   Plumbing         | 1000 |
+--------------------+------+
|    Total (Labour): | 2000 |
+--------------------+------+
|       Grand Total: | 3600 |
+--------------------+------+
```

This is my Rails app so I am fine nesting these lookups i.e. looping through the main wbs_items (i.e. with NULL parent_id) then looping through the children.  I can't seem to figure out the JOIN and what I am sure is a nested sub select etc.  I also don't know which is more efficient - to start with the budget_items or wbs_items then add the joins etc.

Comment: See if [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109048/recursive-bom-bill-of-material-type-query) helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN N.wbs_item_id IS NULL  THEN 'Grand Total' ELSE N.name END) AS '',
(CASE WHEN N.Materials IS NULL  THEN 'Total(Materials)', ELSE N.name END) AS '',
(CASE WHEN N.Labour IS NULL  THEN 'Total(Labour)' ELSE N.name END) AS '',

Total AS ''
FROM(
SELECT (CASE WHEN F.name='Materials' THEN F.name END ) AS 'Materials',
(CASE WHEN F.name='Labour' THEN F.name END ) AS 'Labour',wbs_item_id,SUM(Total) AS 'Total'
FROM(  
SELECT b.wbs_item_id,w.name,w.parent_id,b.Total AS 'Total'
FROM wbs_items w,budgets t
LEFT JOIN  budget_items b  ON  b.wbs_item_id = w.id  AND b.id=t.id
)E,(SELECT name,id FROM wbs_item  WHERE parent_id IS NULL )F
```

WHERE E.wbs_item_id = F.id)N
    GROUP BY Materials,Labour,wbs_item_id WITH ROLLUP;

Comment: `AS 'name'` is invalid SQL, identifiers can't be enclosed in single quotes